# C# Thread.Sleep causes firefox "Connection was Reset"

Tags: c#, firefox, google-chrome, sleep, tcpclient

I'm writing a server that spits out some HTML but I'm having a problem with Chrome and Firefox. Here is the snippet of the code that matters

```
...
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);

listener.Start();

TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
client.SendTimeout = 1000;

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;

...

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
sw.Write(response);
sw.Flush();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

sw.Close();
stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

The response is just plain HTML  .... , without any headers or other meta-data (maybe that's the problem?).
Now what happens is this:

Scenario 1 - There is a Sleep(1000);

Chrome works perfectly, I get the full HTML displayed and it works properly.
Firefox works but after 1 second I get a Problem Loading Page - Connection Was Reset

Scenario 2 - There is no Sleep(1000);

Firefox works perfectly, I get the full HTML displayed and it works properly.
Chrome displays no data or incomplete data and the page "freezes", I can't mark anything or click any buttons.

Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: are you writing your own web server?

Comment: Make sure you also take good care of security, cause yr server will be hacked just like that